# Google Maps API Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I 'm trying to add number of markers whose positions(latitude and longitudes) are fetched from the database,i 'm able to add them to map but

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

method is adding event listener to only the last marker(o.e last city in the database)....

How to add Listner for each markers individually?

Here is my full code ..

=============================================================================

```
 result contains List<City>

    function OnSuccess(result) {
                if (result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    alert(result[i].lat);
                       var myCenter= new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].log);
                        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter});

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: result[i].desc
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

                    }

               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a closure.  What you're doing is redefining the click handler function for every one of your markers.  All the markers, when clicked, will execute this line:

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

Using whatever the values of 'infowindow', 'map' and 'marker' are at that time.  And because marker is created in a loop, this will always be referring to the last marker.

Also `infowindow` is being redefined every time.  So the content will always be that of the last of your results.

Here's how I usually do it.

```
// create this outside of your loop
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ""
});

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var myCenter= new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].log);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        map:  map
    });

    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, result[i].desc);  
}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) { 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(html); 
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    }); 
}
```